# After custom DatabaseInitializer having ObjectContext instance has been disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, autofac, dbcontext

i have autofac with context

```
builder.RegisterType<WebRepositoryContext>().WithParameter("mode", (GlobalVariables.DataBaseMode)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

switch initializer

```
    private static void InitializeDataStore()
    {
        switch (GlobalVariables.DataBaseMode)
        {
            case DataBaseMode.MsSql:
            {
                Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<WebRepositoryContext, Repository.Migrations.Configuration>());

                var configuration = new Repository.Migrations.Configuration();
                var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
                if (migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
                    migrator.Update();
            }
                break;
            case DataBaseMode.Postgres:
            {
                Database.SetInitializer(new PostgresInitializer());
            }

                break;
        }
    }
```

initializer

```
public class PostgresInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<WebRepositoryContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(WebRepositoryContext context)
    {
        //create database
        var h = new PostgresHelper(context);
        h.Create();

        //seed database
        Seed(context);
    }

    protected virtual void Seed(WebRepositoryContext context)
    {

        var seed = new WebRepositorySeed(context);
       seed.Start();
    }
}
```

and when i try to get data in project, like `var mainPage = DataContext.MainPage.First();` in Home Controller i got **"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."**

`public class HomeController : BaseController` where `public WebRepositoryContext DataContext { get; set; }`

probably, initialiser dispose context, which is created by autofac. how to prevent it?

Comment: tag was changed for c#, but it could be problem with postgres

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good (mmmm, it's really a very very bad idea) to have a `DbContext` which lasts for the lifetime of the application:

- The `DbContext` should be as short-lived as possible. Take into account that it caches data and tracks changes. So, as time goes by and operations are donde in the same context, things tsrat to get very complicated
- Using a sinlge `DbContext` will provoke concurrency problems: `DbContext` is not thread-safe. Only its static methods are. So, if you use a single instance for all the MVC threads you'll soon get into all kind of trouble

I prefer to have even a shorterlife time, but things will improve if you use  `InstancePerHttpRequest`. At least, the `DbContext` life will be shorter, and you'll avoid the concurrency errors.

Comment: i've changed to  InstancePerHttpRequest with no luck

Comment: also for mssql all working ok

Comment: Update your question. That'simportant information,so: it works for SQL server but not for PostgreSQL? That made sense for the Postgresql tag that someone removed.

Comment: yes, for sql server code is working normal